# pausing a video after every 10s in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

what i want to do is  pause  a video after every 10s
the video should pause after ever 10s till the video ends

the code given below gives unexpected results
the video pauses fine for the firs time (i.e after 10s)
but when i play again it should pause after 10s   but  in my case it pauses randomly  sometimes at  8s,3s 5s and etc 
what should i do??
please help
thanks!!

```
void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
             VideoControl.Play();
            var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
 }

 private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            VideoControl.Pause();
        }
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark an one post as answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add this in your dispatcherTimer_Tick-Method:

   ```
   dispatcherTimer.Stop();
   ```
2. Move the following part into the constructor:

   ```
   dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
   dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
   dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
   ```
3. Make the DispatcherTimer a global variable.

EDIT: Thats how it should look like:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer; //now your dispatcherTimer is accessible everywhere in this class

        public MyClass()
        {
            _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        }

        void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VideoControl.Play();
            _dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            VideoControl.Pause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do i set  Dispatcher time global??
when i put this code in class  it gives error 
and if put this code in constructor
than dispatertimer  is not accessible in other method

Answer (score 1):

Bring the declaration of the timer out into a private class variable, move a couple lines to the constructor of the class, and stop the timer in the `Tick` handler.

The reason you don't want to keep creating the timer is because there are unmanaged resources involved with a timer and so you're closing that loop.

```
private dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); 

ctor
{
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick); 
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); 
}

void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    VideoControl.Play(); 
    dispatcherTimer.Start(); 
} 

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    dispatchTimer.Stop();
    VideoControl.Pause(); 
}
```

Comment: Note that starting a timer that is currently running will restart it from the beginning.  That's what makes this code work properly if you press play, pause, and then play again real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code in `Tick` event:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
        VideoControl.Pause();
    }
```

You can make `dispatcherTimer` object outside Playclick event and only put `Start()` method inside  `PlayClick` event in following way:

```
var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
public Form1() //// form constructor where you are handling these all event....
{
     dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
     dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
}

void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            VideoControl.Play();
            dispatcherTimer .Start();
}
```

Comment: when i try to access dispatchertimer in PlayClick
it gives the following error

Error: The name 'dispatcherTimer' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @ahmad05 : Sorry for late reply.....I've updated the answer....Go through it.....You can use sender object as Dispatcher timer object as I modified in PlayClick event.....

Comment: @LolCoder I dont think that the sender of PlayClick() is the DispatcherTimer.

Comment: @FlorianGl : Thank you for figuring out.....Now, it's fixed....I've made DispatcherTimer object as global....