# Can't access media element in the event handler how to set it global?

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

i have recently started working on C# and i am very amateur at it
please any help in the problem decirbed below will b  very helpful for me

What i wanted to do is have an access of video_panel  in event handler as-well
but right now i dont know  how to do that 
i tried to declare media element global  and set its value to video_panel
but still no use 
what should i do
what i want to is instead of displaying a message pause a video currently playing

```
namespace Play_pause
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

  static   int index = 0;
  static  System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       video_panel.Play();

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;

        aTimer.Start();




    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {



        index++;
        if (index %2==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't access media element in the event handler/n how to    
            set it global?");




        }

    }    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607440/pausing-a-video-after-every-10s-in-c-sharp/12607558#12607558) again, they show how to make a variable global.

But this wont solve your problem. Since your OnTimedEvent-method is static, you can access only static variables.
I dont think your OnTimedEvent should be static, so try to remove the word "static" and now you can acess global variables (e.g. your video_panel).

Comment: yes the questions are pretty much the same ... i know this
but i am using different technique here  instead of using dispatcherTimer
i am using System.Timers.Time

Comment: well i just did that  ..sorry for being informal.....  but really need help in this case